# Reverse Proxy to App Engine missing Host

Tags: php, google-app-engine, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy pointing to a google appengine api. The api is a shared service layer so I point multiple sites to it via reverse proxies.

mysite1.com > myapp.appspot.com
mysite2.com > myapp.appspot.com

The problem is, in the php script on app engine I'm unable to access the original host name. If I look at the $_SERVER vars all I see is myapp.appspot.com, where I'd like to see mysite1.com

I tried setting the proxy header Host to the main site url and it breaks app engine. Is there a way to get the proxying url from app engine?

Comment: I have solved this using nginx:

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

Comment: Hi Eric, could you add your comment as answer to your question for the benefit of the community? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this using nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

You can then grab the X-Forwarded variables from the $_SERVER array as per the usual in PHP.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-For` is sufficient